# REAL column holding values outside documented range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, data-integrity

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx), the range for REAL values is - 3.40E + 38 to -1.18E - 38, 0 and 1.18E - 38 to 3.40E + 38. However, I have quite a few values beyond that range in my table.

The following query returns lots of very small values and no very large ones:

```
SELECT  MyColumn ,
        *
FROM    data.MyTable
WHERE   MyColumn <> 0
        AND ( MyColumn < CONVERT(REAL, 1.18E-38)
              OR MyColumn > CONVERT(REAL, 3.40E+38)
            )
        AND ( MyColumn < CONVERT(REAL, -3.40E+38)
              OR MyColumn > CONVERT(REAL, -1.18E-38)
            )
```

It is easy to show how these values end up in the table. I cannot insert them directly:

```
CREATE TABLE a(r REAL NULL);
GO
INSERT INTO a(r) VALUES(4.330473E-39);
GO
SELECT r FROM a
GO
DROP TABLE a;

----
0.0
```

But I can divide two columns and get and outside of range value:

```
CREATE TABLE a
  (
    r1 REAL NULL ,
    r2 REAL NULL ,
    r3 REAL NULL
  ) ;
GO
INSERT  INTO a
        ( r1, r2 )
VALUES  ( 4.330473E-38, 1000 ) ;
GO
UPDATE  a
SET     r3 = r1 / r2 ;
SELECT  r1 ,
        r2 ,
        r3
FROM    a

r1            r2            r3
------------- ------------- -------------
4.330473E-38  1000          4.330433E-41
```

So I guess MSDN gives wrong ranges of valid data, correct?
Am I missing anything?

Several people suggested that this is a bug.

What part of this behavior exactly is a bug. is it:

1. Wrong constants documented in MSDN and used in DBCC, as well as wrong threshold for rounding down.
2. Update being able to save wrong values

Comment: Seems like a bug, have you filed it in your favorite place? I guess you could add your own constraint something like `CHECK (r3 > 3.40E-38)` :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can definitely add a constraint, but I would like to understand why SQL Server does not behave as documented.

Comment: `dbcc checktable('a') with DATA_PURITY`: Column "r3" value is out of range for data type "real".  Update column to a legal value. Report it...

Comment: As I said, it seems like a bug. :-)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem like a bug. Once DATA_PURITY has been checked and enabled this should not occur anymore.

Comment: @usr can you post an example that demonstrates it?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov, you are right. See my answer. DBCC CHECKDB reports an error on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Books Online documents only the normal range for single- and double-precision floating point numbers.  The [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) rules also specify floating-point numbers closer to zero than the smallest non-zero normal value, known variously as [denormalized, denormal, and subnormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_numbers) numbers.  From that last link:

> *Denormal numbers provide the guarantee that addition and subtraction of floating-point numbers never underflows; two nearby floating-point
>   numbers always have a representable non-zero difference. Without
>   gradual underflow, the subtraction a−b can underflow and produce zero
>   even though the values are not equal. This can, in turn, lead to
>   division by zero errors that cannot occur when gradual underflow is
>   used.*

SQL Server is following the rules for [single-precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) calculations in the examples posted.  The bug may be that DBCC checks only for *normal* values, and throws an incorrect error message when it encounters a stored denormal value.

Example producing a denormal single-precision value:

```
DECLARE
    @v1 real = 14e-39,
    @v2 real = 1e+07;

-- 1.4013e-045
SELECT @v1 / @v2;
```

Example showing a stored `float` denormal passes DBCC checks:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.b (v1 float PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT b VALUES (POWER(2e0, -1075));
SELECT v1 FROM b; -- 4.94065645841247E-324
DBCC CHECKTABLE(b) WITH DATA_PURITY; -- No errors or warnings
DROP TABLE dbo.b;
```

Comment: Which part is the bug depends on the *intention* of the SQL Server programmers. It appears, from the documentation (and `DBCC CHECKDB`), that the *intention* was to only store normalized numbers.

Comment: Indeed, this proves that there is a bug in `DBCC CHECKDB`. Being able to store denormal floats might or might not be one, depending on the design decision made by the product team. +1

Comment: +1, but if there is a bug in DBCC, then MSDN is wrong too, correct?

Comment: @SQLkiwi incomplete rather than wrong? Maybe. I am not sure why it would matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in SQL Server. The last script you post is a nice repro. Add one line to it at the end:

```
DBCC CHECKDB WITH data_purity
```

This fails with:

> Msg 2570, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Page (1:313), slot 0 in object ID
>   357576312, index ID 0, partition ID 1801439851932155904, alloc unit ID
>   2017612634169999360 (type "In-row data"). Column "r3" value is out of
>   range for data type "real".  Update column to a legal value.

This proves it is a bug. I suggest you file a bug with [Microsoft Connect for SQL Server](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx).

Comment: +1, but: What part of this behavior exactly is a bug. is it:

 1. Wrong constants documented in MSDN and used in DBCC, as well as wrong threshold for rounding down.
 2. Update being able to save wrong values

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov, no. 2 is the bug: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle-How-to-tell-if-data-purity-checks-will-be-run.aspx ("In SQL Server versions prior to 2005, it was possible to import invalid data values into a database. These invalid values could cause query execution problems, or possibly even wrong results. In 2005, when the import 'holes' were closed"). They *should* be closed. This isn't official documentation but I guess the team will regard it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I will make sure that undocumented values do not get saved via UPDATE/MERGE command.

Comment: @SQLkiwi, can you elaborate on that? Column r3 is outside of the documented range which is exactly what `DBCC CHECKDB` is reporting. I think that is convincing evidence. Paul Randals post seems to support this view, too.